# notepad++ and nppautoindent

Tags: notepad++, indentation, auto-indent

I have installed the nppautoindent plugin into the notepad++ editor. I see no autoindenting effect. I am using PHP. Can some one help me get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What version of Notepad++ and NPPAutoIndent are you using? I'm using Notepad++ version 5.8.7 and NPPAutoIndent version 1.2.
I'm not familiar with the way the plugin is supposed to work but I think I got the autoindenting to work.

First off, go to Settings->Preferences->Misc and ensure that Auto-indent is *not* ticked. Then go to Plugins->NPPAutoIndent and ensure Smart Indent *is* selected. Once that is done I get indentation like this when I press Return after each line:

```
function test() {
    return "Test";
}
```

This is what it looks like otherwise:

```
function test() {
return "Test";
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: How do I indent code which already exists ? Is there keyboard shortcut like ctrl+shift+f which eclipse IDE has ?

Comment: @Steam: I'm not sure if that operation is supported by NPPAutoIndent. As an alternative, you could check out [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1504) answer which uses the Indent By Fold plugin.